What techniques are there to take averages and errors in a Monte Carlo simulation in C? Can my code be improved?
I'm trying to perform a Monte Carlo simulation in C and these are the steps I'm following:

We assume an infinite reservoir compound of CO and NO molecules with partial pressures CO and NO(= 1 − CO), respectively.

The reservoir is in contact with a surface which is simulated by means of a square lattice of 64×64. Periodic boundary conditions are applied to avoid edge effects.

The equilibrium coverages are measured as a function of CO. To find the critical points, a run each up to 50000 Monte Carlo cycles (MCS) needs to be carried out.If the run completes 50000 MCS without the lattice getting poisoned (surface saturation), the particular point is considered to be within SRS.

In order to obtain the coverages of CO, N and O, the initial 20000 MCS are disregarded for equilibrium and averages are taken over the subsequent 30000 MCS. The values of coverages/production rate are obtained after 10 MCS, so that the final values are an average of 3000 configurations.

The CO or the NO molecules are selected randomly with relative probabilities CO and NO, respectively.

A surface site is picked up at random and the steps involved in the simulation are as follows:


(a) If the selected molecule is NO and the picked
site is empty, then the four nearest neighbours of the selected site are scanned at random. If all the sites areoccupied, the trial ends. In the case that any adjacent site is vacant, NO dissociates into N and O which occupy the vacant sites with equal probability. The nearest neighbouring sites of adsorbed N and O atoms in step are then searched for the presence of CO and N respectively. If there is a CO (N), then CO2 (N2) is formed, leaving two vacant sites.
(b) In the case that CO is selected, one of the following events occurs: (i) if the picked site is vacant, then CO is adsorbed on the chosen vacant site
as in step. The nearest neighbours of this adsorbed CO molecule are scanned for the presence of an adsorbed O atom in order to complete reaction step. In the case that the O atom is found, CO2 is formed which immediately desorbs leaving two empty sites from the surface and the trial ends. (ii) If the picked site is occupied by the O atom, then CO is co-adsorbed on that O atom with probability . This coadsorbed CO then reacts with O at that site with unit probability to form CO2.
This is the code I have so far:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "pcg_basic.h" // Include the PCG header file
 
#define NMAX 64
#define MMAX 64
#define TIME 50000
#define WARMUP 20000
#define AVERAGE_START 10
#define num_simulations 50
 
typedef enum { EMPTY, CO, O, N } LAT_ELEM;
 
typedef struct {
    double CO_coverage;
    double O_coverage;
    double N_coverage;
} Coverage;
 
// Initialize the PCG RNG state
pcg32_random_t rng;
 
///////////////////Function Prototypes ////////////////////////////
Coverage calculate_coverage(LAT_ELEM lattice[NMAX * MMAX]);
int find_random_site();
void print_lattice(LAT_ELEM lattice[NMAX * MMAX]);
int find_random_neighbor(int site);
void find_nearest_neighbors(int site, int exclude, int neighbors[4]);
void add_CO(LAT_ELEM lattice[NMAX * MMAX], int *co2_count, double coadsorption_probability);
void add_NO_dissociate(LAT_ELEM lattice[NMAX * MMAX], int *co2_count, int *n2_count);
void write_lattice_to_csv(int N, int M, LAT_ELEM lattice[N * M], double XCO);
double mean(double *array, int size);
double std_dev(double *array, int size);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 
int main() {
    clock_t start = clock();
 
    // Seed the PCG RNG
    pcg32_srandom_r(&rng, time(NULL) ^ (intptr_t)&printf, (intptr_t)&rng);
 
    LAT_ELEM lattice[NMAX * MMAX]; 
 
    double XCO_values[num_simulations];
    double co_coverages_mean[num_simulations];
    double o_coverages_mean[num_simulations];
    double n_coverages_mean[num_simulations];
    double co2_rates_mean[num_simulations];
    double n2_rates_mean[num_simulations];
    double co_coverages_std_dev[num_simulations];
    double o_coverages_std_dev[num_simulations];
    double n_coverages_std_dev[num_simulations];
    double co2_rates_std_dev[num_simulations];
    double n2_rates_std_dev[num_simulations];
     
    double coadsorption_probability = 0.000;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < num_simulations; i++) {
        double XCO = i / (double)(num_simulations - 1);  // This ensures XCO ranges from 0 to 1
        XCO_values[i] = XCO;
 
        // Initialize the lattice as empty 
        for (int j = 0; j < NMAX * MMAX; j++) {
            lattice[j] = EMPTY;
        }
 
        int co2_count = 0, n2_count = 0;
        Coverage sum_coverage = {0};
        double sum_co2_rate = 0, sum_n2_rate = 0;
        int data_points = 0;
 
        // Warmup phase
        for (int t = 0; t < WARMUP; t++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < NMAX * MMAX; k++) {
                double r = ldexp(pcg32_random_r(&rng) & 0x7FFFFFFF, -31);
                if (r < XCO) {
                    add_CO(lattice, &co2_count, coadsorption_probability);
                     
                } else {
                    add_NO_dissociate(lattice, &co2_count, &n2_count);    
                    //add_NO_molecule(lattice, &co2_count, &n2_count);  
                     
                }
            }
        }
        // Data collection phase
        int data_collection_steps = (TIME - WARMUP) / AVERAGE_START;
        double co_coverages[data_collection_steps];
        double o_coverages[data_collection_steps];
        double n_coverages[data_collection_steps];
        double co2_rates[data_collection_steps];
        double n2_rates[data_collection_steps];
 
        for (int t = WARMUP; t < TIME; t++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < NMAX * MMAX; k++) {
                double r = ldexp(pcg32_random_r(&rng) & 0x7FFFFFFF, -31);
                if (r < XCO) {
                    add_CO(lattice, &co2_count, coadsorption_probability);
                     
                } else {
                    add_NO_dissociate(lattice, &co2_count, &n2_count);
                    //add_NO_molecule(lattice, &co2_count, &n2_count);  
                                     
                }
            }
 
            // Collect data every 10 MCS steps
            if ((t - WARMUP) % AVERAGE_START == 0) {
                Coverage current_coverage = calculate_coverage(lattice);
                sum_coverage.CO_coverage += current_coverage.CO_coverage;
                sum_coverage.O_coverage += current_coverage.O_coverage;
                sum_coverage.N_coverage += current_coverage.N_coverage;
 
                co_coverages[data_points] = current_coverage.CO_coverage;
                o_coverages[data_points] = current_coverage.O_coverage;
                n_coverages[data_points] = current_coverage.N_coverage;
 
                double co2_rate = (double)co2_count / (NMAX * MMAX);
                double n2_rate = (double)n2_count / (NMAX * MMAX);
                 
                sum_co2_rate += co2_rate;
                sum_n2_rate += n2_rate;
 
                co2_rates[data_points] = co2_rate;
                n2_rates[data_points] = n2_rate;
 
                // Reset counts for the next data point
                co2_count = 0;
                n2_count = 0;
 
                data_points++;
                 //new
            }
         
        }
 
        // Calculate averages and standard deviations
        co_coverages_mean[i] = sum_coverage.CO_coverage / data_points;
        o_coverages_mean[i] = sum_coverage.O_coverage / data_points;
        n_coverages_mean[i] = sum_coverage.N_coverage / data_points;
        co2_rates_mean[i] = sum_co2_rate / data_points;
        n2_rates_mean[i] = sum_n2_rate / data_points;
 
        co_coverages_std_dev[i] = std_dev(co_coverages, data_points);
        o_coverages_std_dev[i] = std_dev(o_coverages, data_points);
        n_coverages_std_dev[i] = std_dev(n_coverages, data_points);
        co2_rates_std_dev[i] = std_dev(co2_rates, data_points);
        n2_rates_std_dev[i] = std_dev(n2_rates, data_points);
    }
 
    // Write the data from the arrays to a text file
    FILE *file = fopen("0-coadsorption-disociative-PCO-0-000.txt", "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < num_simulations; i++) {
        fprintf(file, "%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", XCO_values[i], co_coverages_mean[i], o_coverages_mean[i], n_coverages_mean[i], co2_rates_mean[i], n2_rates_mean[i], co_coverages_std_dev[i], o_coverages_std_dev[i], n_coverages_std_dev[i], co2_rates_std_dev[i], n2_rates_std_dev[i]);
    }
 
    fclose(file);
    printf("The results were printed in the file\n");
    clock_t end = clock();
    double cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Total runtime: %f seconds\n", cpu_time_used);
 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

The problem is that for the values of yco until 0.20 I'm getting peaks in the coverages and big error bars (they can be seen in the plot of the CO coverages vs yco) for values of the probability of coadsorption different than zero. For such a probability equal to zero, i get the "base case" and everything looks as it should. I was wondering if my code follows exactly the steps I mentioned before (which come from a paper), or if is there a better way to take averages inside my main function.

Note: I could share the details of the other functions in my code if it's needed.

Hi @Auyk, what do you mean by "coverage"? Is it the fraction of lattice points that are occupied by an atom/molecule of a given chemical substance? May be trivial, bu I just wanted to be sure I understand

(this is irrelevant for answering the question, but I'm curious) What is the final application of your simulation? Are you optimizing some cathalytic design for capturing pollutants after a combustion stage?

@Rigel Yes, the coverages is the fraction of atoms/molecules adsorbed in an LxL surface. At first, I want to reproduce the results obtained in a paper (I can share it if it's needed) where they follow the steps decribed above. The main goal is to study the effects of several reaction mechanisms like coadsorption, desorption, difussion, etc.

How long are your chains, and how does the picture change if, for example, you make your chains 10 times as long?

@WolfgangBangerth well, I'm taking averages every 10 MCS. That gives me 3000 configurations and if I make them larger my results doesn't vary much. That's why I'm doubting if I implemented the algorithm correctly.
